# combing result of two queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, aggregation-framework

my collection is like

```
{ queid:"1', date:'07/24/2013', resolved:'true' }
```

i want to get counts like

```
{date:'07/24/2013',countquestion:10,resolved:5}
{date:'07/23/2013',countquestion:5,resolved:2}
```

presently i am getting counts for number of questions using

```
que.aggregate({$group:"$date",count{$sum:1}})
```

and resolved using

```
que.aggregate({$match:{resolved:true}},{$group:"$date",count{$sum:1}})
```

combining both in java program. Is there a better way to do this query and combine results.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/cond/) operator. Just pay attention to `resolved` field, it should be a boolean.

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$date",
        "countquestion": {
            "$sum": 1
        },
        "resolved": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "$resolved", 1, 0 ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```